# Make Notification Div Fade Out When User Click Anywhere Outside The Notification Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making website that have notification 'button'. When user click this button, notification div will appear at the bottom of the button.

I want to make its behaviour like notifacation in facebook. the notification will disappear when user click anywhere outside the notification div element.

So far, i've succeed to make the notification div to fade in and fade out when the notification button clicked. i'm using jquery to do this.

but, i don't know how to make it fade out when user click anywhere outside the notification div.

Can anyone help me?

Here is my code that i've made:

```
<div id="notifikasi" style="position:relative; cursor:pointer">Notification<sup style="padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px; background: red"></sup>
    <div id="theNotif" style="position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 0px; background: #fff; color: #000; border: solid 1px #999; z-index: 999; padding: 10px 20px 10px 0px; width:200px; display:none">
        <ul>
            <li>Some Notification</li>
            <li>Some Notification</li>
            <li>Some Notification</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$('#notifikasi').click(function(){
    if($('#theNotif').css('display') == 'none'){
        $('#theNotif').fadeIn('fast');
    }
    else{
        $('#theNotif').fadeOut('fast');
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var myDiv = $("#theNotif");
    if (myDiv.has(e.target).length === 0)
        myDiv.hide();
});
```

Comment: thanks, @JonH ! It's worked ! But I dont understand how does it work?

Comment: @TikasMamed - Its fairly simple take a look here: http://api.jquery.com/has/ the mouseup event can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/ it triggers the mouseup event once you have released your mouse click.  You can try it on the sample jquery page (at the bottom).

Comment: Thanks. I've never know or use `has()` or `mouseup()` before. It's really solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
$('#notifikasi').click(function(){
    $('#theNotif').fadeIn('fast', function() {
        $(document).one('click', function(e) {
            $('#theNotif').fadeOut('fast');
        });
    });
});

// prevent triggering when clicking the actual notification
$('#theNotif').click(function() { return false; });​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LZDXN/)

Once the notification has faded in, a one-time-only click listener will be added to the document listening to any click.

---

**Edit**

Having played around like this a bit myself, I've come to the conclusion that `.one` is not really as useful here as I first imagined, as it requires a few other workarounds. The reason I used it was that it irked me to have to constantly listen to every single document click, just to cover the scenario where a notification was open.

I've decided instead that a neater way would be to use bind and unbind.

```
function closeNotification(e) {
   if($(e.target).closest('#theNotif').length > 0) {
      // notification or child of notification was clicked; ignore
      return;
   }

   $('#theNotif').fadeOut('fast');
   $(document).unbind('click', closeNotification);
};

$('#notifikasi').click(function(){
    $('#theNotif').fadeIn('fast', function() {
        $(document).bind('click', closeNotification);
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LZDXN/1/)

The code above is conceptually rather similar to the original code. After fade-in, a click listener is registered at the document. This time, a check is made *within* the document click listener, to see if the clicked element was `#theNotif` or a child of `#theNotif`, in which case the close function exits immediately.

Otherwise, it proceeds to close the notification and then immediately unbind the listener.

Note that you'll have to use a named function, not an anonymous inline one as you might be used to in jQuery, in order to be able to properly unbind it.

Comment: But this will only work if he clicks within the div #notifikasi no ?

Comment: @David Hedlund Thanks, David. I've tried your code but it's not working. after i clicked the button, the div fade in and soon fade out too.

Comment: @TikasMamed: Yes, in my original post I added the document click listener too early, and it fired immediately. See my updated answer.

Comment: @JonH: No, the listener is on the document, as it is in your example; see the demo.

Comment: @JonH: Not in that respect, no.

Comment: @TikasMamed: Does the demo not work for you? The demo uses the code I've posted, and works fine for me.

Comment: @David Hedlund: it's work! And also thanks for the prevent triggering. It's new for me.

Comment: and i think `$('#theNotif').click(function() { return false; });​
` must be placed inside `one()` function.

Comment: anyway, when i put link at #theNotif, i cannot click the link. #theNotif is disappear (fadeOut)

Comment: @TikasMamed: yeah, it wasn't really a very solid solution, it turns out. I've modified it a bit.

Comment: To be quite honest, the easiest way would of been to use `has()` as I have done above.  The reason being is the target click is checked in my if condition and if the control is part of the div (child of the parent) then the notification does not disappear.  If you are outside of the div `has(e.target)` returns 0 and the condition is satisfied and the div is hidden.  A lot less code and not much to break it.

Comment: @JonH: I'm aware. I would just personally avoid a solution that means there's always going to be some (however little) piece of code executed during every single click in the entire document, just to cover the perhaps rare cases where there is a notification to hide.

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable when mouse moves over notifikasi (say a=1), unset it when moves outside.
Similarly for theNotif.
Now

```
$(document).click(function(){
    if(a == 0){
        if($('#theNotif').css('display') == 'block' || $('#theNotif').css('display') == ''){
            $('#theNotif').fadeOut('fast');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You are assigning a to 0.  This has too much of a dependency and can easily break.

Comment: opps, it was intended to be equality operator not assignment

Comment: Even with what you have posted it still  does not help the OP.  For one thing, a is undefined upon entry.

Comment: Right, I take it for obvious that a should be defined to 0. Set to 1 if mouseover event occurs. Its a hint, not a fully tested exact code. The method works fine, I've used it.